# Wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3500

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, dell-vostro

I've just installed Windows 7 32bit on my Dell Vostro 3500 (Intel).

For some reason wireless is not working so I'm assuming I am missing the correct drivers.

I went (among other places) [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=19855&ProdId=2259&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%207,%2032-bit*&DownloadType=Software%20Applications) and downloaded and tried both (just in case because I couldn't tell the difference).

I got this:

[image]

I'm not sure the above link is what I wanted but it made some sense.

So where can I find the appropriate drivers?

---

### <sup>I can't post as an answer yet.</sup>
EDIT: Answer

I found the necessary drivers [here](http://es.driverscollection.com/?file_cid=42861871899f817516540482d5c).

I installed and it is working without a problem.

The above isn't an official link, so use it at your own risk but on my PC, it worked just fine. I think the linked site is trust worthy though.

[Here](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R270598&SystemID=VOS_N_3700&servicetag=&os=W764%20&osl=en&deviceid=23574&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=5&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=399086) is (what I think is) the official driver but I have **not** tried it.

I hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: Please ask if you need more information on my hardware.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @KCotreau sorry! 32 bit. I edited the question. I knew I was forgettingh something...

Comment: brilliant, your answer worked! I tried every single dell driver, and nothing worked. SHAME ON YOU DELL

Comment: @moeTi glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not be going to the Intel site. Sometimes, large OEM's get slight modifications of either firmware and/or drivers. You should go to the Dell site, and enter your Service Tag to get your exact drivers.

Try [this driver package from Dell](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R253445&SystemID=VOS_N_3500&servicetag=&os=W732&osl=en&deviceid=22158&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=5&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=5&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=371209). It has both 32-bit and 64-bit drivers.

Comment: +1 That make sense, thanks for the answer! I'll let you know as soon as I finish downloading/installing. BTW that is one heavy driver!

Comment: NO KIDDING on that. 360MB for a wireless driver???

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I run the manual test and I gave me this http://i.imgur.com/WphX9.png there seems to be a problem with the Hardware...

Comment: Now that it is downloaded, see if you can go into Device Manager, and change the driver for the wireless card, and browse to the location you just installed the software to. It may still be using the wrong one since they are so close, so go manually pick it.

Comment: not sure if I understood you. (Sorry it's been really long since the last time I used windows!) I went to Device Manager and I saw this: http://i.imgur.com/Kd4IE.png I tried the option to update drivers but it didn't work with any of the "other devices". I'm still not sure what you asked me to do. Thank you for all the help btw!

Comment: I found the solution. Thank you **very** much for all your help anyway!!! I've edited my question because I can't post answers yet. Thanks again.